# Pseudo-element ::before being set wrongly

Tags: javascript, css, ag-grid

I'm trying to implement a cell that has multiple icons on an `ag grid` table. I'm trying to do that trough `cellRenderer`.

```js
cellRenderer: function (params) {
  if (params.value === params.data.signal_flag) {
    let thinCircle1 = thinCircle2 = thinCircle3 = "-thin"
    if (params.value === 1) {
      thinCircle1 = '';
    } 
    const flagIcons = `<span>
      <i id="1" class='fa fa-circle${thinCircle1}' style="color: green;"></i>
      <i id="2" class='fa fa-circle${thinCircle2}' style="color: yellow;"></i>
      <i id="3" class='fa fa-circle${thinCircle3}' style="color: red;"></i>
    </span>`;
    return flagIcons
  }
}
```

For some reason only the first icon appears on cell, inspecting the element I found out that there is a psedo-element being called `::before`. I think this is some kind of default behavior from `ag grid`, but I couldn't find how to disable it on documentation.

---

## SOLVED

I was using a deprecated fontawesome class, the project uses 5.x and I was trying to import an older class.

Comment: Font Awesome outputs a `::before` element, which is the icon you've selected. Could you  make a minimal reproducible example in which we can experience your issue?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/GffbPJbC1opJRiqe for some reason on this simple example it's working. I need to figure out what is wrong on my real project

Comment: I was inspecting the element and just saw that on this working demo all icons get a `::before` between `<i>` tags. On the broken project only the one that is being rendered is getting the `::before` tag. Do you have any ideia how could I force the tag on all elements?